# Power cut while cutting and pasting a file

Tags: windows-7, windows

I was cutting and pasting a backup image from one location to another and had a power cut. Does this effect the integrity of the original file in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It shouldn't. Deletion is afterwards copying.

But, did the power come back on ? Is the original file still there ? Why not check for yourself ?

Comment: Hi, yes the power came back 2 mins later. The file is still in the original source location and same size (so copying all of it again). I could test this with a small installer app but didn't think of this till after.

Comment: If it is like you say, I don't think there is any need for that. Just copy it again, and keep on moving ... :-)

Comment: @dotnetdev there's a command "fc"just do fc file1 file2  and that will compare the files, but it looks fine. and should be fine anyway.